# Simplify Angular Functions that uses $q.defer() to promise chaining

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I would like to simplify the following `AngularJs` code, and specifically the `$q.defer()` and `promise` method.

I saw a blog giving some examples of the wrong use of `$q.defer()` [here](http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/), and would appreciate your input and tips in rewriting my code below to comply to this simpler method.

> **This is an example from the Blog:**
>
> *This:*
>
> ```
> var defer = $q.defer();
> $http.get('options.json').success(function(result) {
>   defer.resolve(result);
> });
> return defer.promise;
> ```
>
> *can be changed to:*
>
> ```
> return $http.get('options.json').then(function(response) {
>   return response.data;
> });
> ```

**Below is 3 functions (lets call it "stages" for this example) from 3 different services to return the appropriate data:**

**Stage 1: SocialMediaUserService**

```
this.checkSocialMediaSubscription = function () {

  var isSubscribed = $q.defer();

  GetUserAccessService.returnBrandProfileID().then(function (brandProfileID) {

      if (brandProfileID === 0) {
          isSubscribed.resolve(false);
      }

      else {
          isSubscribed.resolve(true);
      }
  });

  return isSubscribed.promise;
};
```

**Stage 2: GetUserAccessService**

```
this.returnBrandProfileID = function () {

  var brandProfileID = $q.defer();

  if (angular.isUndefined($sessionStorage.brandProfileID)) {

      GetDataService.getItems('GetUserAccess/' + $cookies.get('authenticationID'))

      .success(function (accessObject) {

          $sessionStorage.brandProfileID = accessObject.FusewareID;
          brandProfileID.resolve(accessObject.FusewareID);
      })

      .error(function (error, status) {
          console.error('Fuseware API error: ' + error + ' Status message: ' + status);
      });
  }

  else {
      brandProfileID.resolve($sessionStorage.brandProfileID);
  }

  return brandProfileID.promise;

};
```

**Stage 3: GetDataService**

```
.factory('GetDataService', ['$http', 'WebServiceURL', function ($http, WebServiceURL) {

  var DataFactory = {};

  DataFactory.getItems = function (ServiceParameter) {

      console.log(WebServiceURL + '/' + ServiceParameter);

      return $http.get(WebServiceURL + '/' + ServiceParameter, { cache: true });

  };

  return DataFactory;

  }
```

Comment: In addition to what Tobi already said, you can check some libraries that will help you with chaining promises like the following: https://github.com/kriskowal/q or https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird

Comment: Thank you for the reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should omit $q.defer if you already have a promise you are working with in a function and leverage promise chaining instead.

I'll give an example for your Stage 1:

```
function () {
     return GetUserAccessService.returnBrandProfileID().then(function (brandProfileID) {

        if (brandProfileID === 0) {
           return false;
        }
        else {
           return true;
        }
     });
}
```

What we use here is that you just can use "return" inside the **.then** function callback which will internally resolve the promise returned by **.then**. This is why we can return the chained promise instead of $q.defer() in the main function.

**Addition**: look at it like this: Any value you return inside the **.then** callback will be wrapped into [Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) and this will create a promise based on the value, when it is not already one.